# How to capture and handle unhandled exceptions that happens inside Task.Factory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, task-parallel-library

I have coded this inside App startup

inside `App.xaml.cs`

```
public App()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

    currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

    DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;

    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Application_DispatcherUnhandledException);

    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += new EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>(Application_DispatcherUnhandledException2);

    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;


}

private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    writeMessage(e.Exception);
}

private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    writeMessage(e.Exception);
}

private static void writeMessage(Exception e)
{
    string srMsg = e.InnerException?.Message;

    if (srMsg != null)
    {
        srMsg += "\r\n\r\nStack\r\n" + e.InnerException?.StackTrace;
    }

    if (srMsg == null)
    {
        srMsg = e.Message + "\r\n\r\nStack\r\n" + e.StackTrace;
    }

    srMsg += "\r\n\r\n*********\r\n\r\n";

    File.AppendAllText("global_errors.txt", srMsg);

}

private static void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException2(object o, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    writeMessage(e.Exception);
}

private static void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    writeMessage(e.Exception);
}

private static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    writeMessage(e);
}
```

However, this is still not capturing task factory errors

For example

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Nothing proposed in this thread works [WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler/)

Comment: It's not an unhandled exception though. The Task wrapper catches and holds the exception. You could try changing the signature of your button click to `private async void Button_Click` and then doing `await Task.Run(() => test.Example(););`. Can't test it here though, so not sure if it'll work. Note here that, unless some specific cases, `Task.Run` is the replacement of `TaskFactory.StartNew`: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: Did you take a look at the [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8) event? I successfully catched 'unhanded exceptions' in any threads with it in the past. The only drawback is, that you will get **any** thrown error, no matter if you are using a try and catch or not.

Comment: @Knoop adding wait surely fixes problem but then my screen becomes unresponsive because it locks the main thread

Comment: @Twenty it captures the error but i cant see why error happened. Input string was not in a correct format.

Stack
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal). it shows message bu not the stack trace

Comment: Mhh, I just tested it on my own and I get the StackTrace along with the `FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs`. Are you sure that `e.Exception.StackTrace` is null?

Comment: @Twenty not null but do not provide useful information as well. shows generic class like    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: @Twenty and another not null stacktrace. but there is no other one    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)

Comment: What about using `StackTrace`, I managed to get the full `StackTrace`, `var st = new StackTrace(); var frames = st.GetFrames();`. Try to give it a shot.

Comment: @Twenty still i could not get the error happened line. how did you manage? perhaps you can post a full answer

Comment: Seems like best solution is garbage collecting on application exit. or periodically garbage collecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the StackTrace can be done in several ways, it really depends on what fits your needs the best. Anyhow I would suggest you, to try the following.

1. Add a callback to the [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8) event, at the start of your project e.g. before the errors occur which you want to catch/log. This could look something like the following:

```cs
public static Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
}

private static void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{

}
```

2. After that, add the [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) in the `CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException` method. It will hold the current `StackTrace` as a `string`. From my testing it includes the `FileName` and `FileLineNumber`.

```cs
var currentStackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;

// Now it is on to you on what you want to do with the StackTrace. This could be some kind of logging.
```

---

Note that this will log **ALL** exceptions thrown by the `AppDomain`, no matter if they are handled by the code e.g. `try/catch`.

Comment: 1 more thing. i see that this will catch try/catch handled ones as well. are there any way to know whether exception was gracefully handled or not? so that i would not log it

Comment: Sadly you **can't** do that as I said in the answer. As the name suggests `FirstChanceException` it will get executed at the very first moment that an exception gets thrown, even before a `try/catch`. What you could do, is creating some sort of custom logging which would allow your application to tell the logger that a certain error got handled. For example by calling a method each time you hit an exception and a `try/catch` handles it.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown only if you observe the `Task` by for example calling `Wait()` or `.Result` or accessing its `Exception` property.

Unobserved exceptions are not thrown unless you use the [`<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8) configuration element to revert back to the behavior that was the default in .NET Framework 4 and terminates the process:

```
<runtime>
  <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

If you really want to catch the exception, you should do it in the delegate that you pass to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You may wrap this functionality in an extension method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34633737/7252182).

Comment: it has a nice question "This will require to add .Catch<> block to every invocation of Task.Run? Is there a way to auto-add it to all invocations?" if i have to write for every task it is not global :D

Comment: Also adding  <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> changes nothing :/

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Yes, it does. The event handler for `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` is invoked when the unobserved task is collected.

Comment: The garbage collection of the faulted task is not deterministic. It may happen after short or long time. Unless you call `GC.Collect()` explicitly in your code.